# Returned multiple items from dict is showing duplicate items in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am building a simple react app and I am trying to `return specific items if matched from passed argument in function`.

**In Brief :-**

I made a function to check if given argument's ids is in function's dict or not, if passed argument's ids matches any of the dict keys then return all matching `dict values`. But It is showing duplicate results in almost every `map` item in `App` component

App.js

```
function CheckItems(ids) {
  const dictToCheck = [
        {"id": 13, "type": "good"},
        {"id": 14, "type": "bad"},
        {"id": 15, "type": "excellent"},
        {"id": 16, "type": "fabulous"},
        {"id": 17, "type": "not good"},
        {"id": 19, "type": "not bad"},
        {"id": 15, "type": "not gross"},
        {"id": 16, "type": "junk"},
        {"id": 39, "type": "trash"},
  ]


    return (
      {
        dictToCheck.map(({id, type})  => 
          ids.map((ids) => 
            id == ids && <div>{type}</div>
          )
        )
      }
    )
}

function App() {
    const apiItems = [
        {
            "title": "First Job",
            "description": "Unknown",
            "ids": [
             13, 15
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Second Job",
            "description": "Unknown",
            "ids": [
             39, 16
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Third Job",
            "description": "Unknown",
            "ids": [
             17
            ]
        }
    ]

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Items</h2>

            {apiItems.map((item) =>
               <div>
                  {item.title}

                  {CheckItems(item.ids)} // [13, 16]

               </div>
            }

        </div>
    ), 
}
```

When I run above function then It is showing duplicate items returned like

```
First Job
bad, excellent, bad

Second Job
trash, junk, trash

Third Job
not good, not good
```

**Expecting response in App component :-**

```
First Job
bad, excellent

Second Job
trash, junk

Third Job
not good
```

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all replace your duplicate ids.

I would recommend that you do a second map function in you app and return only the values in you CheckItems function. Something like this:

```
function CheckItem(id) {
  const dictToCheck = [
        {"id": 13, "type": "good"},
        {"id": 14, "type": "bad"},
        {"id": 15, "type": "excellent"},
        {"id": 16, "type": "fabulous"},
        {"id": 17, "type": "not good"},
        {"id": 19, "type": "not bad"},
        {"id": 20, "type": "not gross"},
        {"id": 21, "type": "junk"},
        {"id": 39, "type": "trash"},
  ]

    const targetType = dictToCheck.find(item => item.id == id);
    return targetType.type
}

function App() {
    const apiItems = [
        {
            "title": "First Job",
            "description": "Unknown",
            "ids": [
             13, 15
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Second Job",
            "description": "Unknown",
            "ids": [
             39, 16
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Third Job",
            "description": "Unknown",
            "ids": [
             17
            ]
        }
    ]

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Items</h2>

            {apiItems.map((item) =>
               <div>
                  {item.title}

                  {item.ids.map((id, index) => {
                      <div>{CheckItem(id)}</div>
                  })}
               </div>
            }

        </div>
    ), 
}
```

or if you want to keep that the CheckItems function to returns a HTML emlement

```
function CheckItems(ids) {
  const dictToCheck = [
        {"id": 13, "type": "good"},
        {"id": 14, "type": "bad"},
        {"id": 15, "type": "excellent"},
        {"id": 16, "type": "fabulous"},
        {"id": 17, "type": "not good"},
        {"id": 19, "type": "not bad"},
        {"id": 20, "type": "not gross"},
        {"id": 21, "type": "junk"},
        {"id": 39, "type": "trash"},
  ]

const targetItems = dictToCheck.filter(item => ids.includes(item.id));

    return (
      {
        targetItems.map(item => 
          <div>{item.type}</div>
        )
      }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks But it is showing `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')` in console when I run the function

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked. But You did a mistake, It should `ids.includes()` not `arr2.includes()`

Answer (score 0):

This can help, filter the list according to the id before mapping:

```
function CheckItems(ids) {
  let dictToCheck = [
        {"id": 13, "type": "good"},
        {"id": 14, "type": "bad"},
        {"id": 15, "type": "excellent"},
        {"id": 16, "type": "fabulous"},
        {"id": 17, "type": "not good"},
        {"id": 19, "type": "not bad"},
        {"id": 15, "type": "not gross"},
        {"id": 16, "type": "junk"},
        {"id": 39, "type": "trash"},
  ]

     
    let uniq_elt = {};
    dictToCheck=dictToCheck.filter(obj => !uniq_elt[obj.id] && (uniq_elt[obj.id] = true))
    return (
      {
        dictToCheck.filter(item=> ids.includes(item.id)).map(({id, type})  => 
          <div>{type}</div>
        )
      }
    )
}

function App() {
    const apiItems = [
        {
            "title": "First Job",
            "description": "Unknown",
            "ids": [
             13, 15
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Second Job",
            "description": "Unknown",
            "ids": [
             39, 16
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Third Job",
            "description": "Unknown",
            "ids": [
             17
            ]
        }
    ]

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Items</h2>

            {apiItems.map((item) =>
               <div>
                  {item.title}

                  {CheckItems(item.ids)}

               </div>
            }

        </div>
    ), 
}
```

Comment: `ids` is also a list, that's why I was using `.map()` for it, But It is not showing anything. It is showing blank

Comment: Hello @Vanesseaa, can you check the update of the filter?

Comment: Thanks, But It is still showing duplicate results in `App` component. It is showing same results it was showing with  `two map` functions